# Weird Trail Behind Moving Object During Animation Render

Tags: rendering, animation

So I'm fairly new to Blender and decided to try out Blender Guru's tutorials. I got to the Glass Smash project (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9L8qOq1Shiw&t=3635s) and was able to follow along pretty well. Everything seemed to work until the final rendered animation where I came upon an issue that I don't even know where to begin solving. The bullet leaves behind a weird trail as it moves. I don't know why this happens, or how to fix it. My best guess is it has something to do with the motion blur, but that's basically an educated guess from a newbie like me. Any help is appreciated.[image: ren]

Comment: You've already asked this question, have you checked the Motion Blur option in the Render panel?

Comment: Yes, the motion blur option is currently on. If that is the problem, I don't know why it would only be affecting the bullet.

Comment: Yes that must be the problem, I don't enough about the mtion blur though, it may have to do with the parameters? maybe someone will answer your question

Comment: @SeanHorgan try to deactivate it and see if it makes any difference. You may have to adjust animation speed or your f-stops to get good looking results. BTW a bullet isn't fired with its case.

Comment: Ok, looks like it was indeed the motion blur. I don't know why that happens, or how to fix it so I have the blur but no trail, but for now at least I ave identified the source of the problem.